# Accessing Local Variables Inside a Python Generator

Tags: python, scripting, iterator, generator

How would you access a local variable defined inside a Python generator from outside the generator?

I have a case where my generator manipulates a local state, and for unittests I want to inspect this state to ensure it contains the correct values.

I can't store the state to an instance variable (e.g. self.state = blah), because I might be creating multiple generators from the same class instance, meaning the generators might overwrite each other's state. I also can't return the state in the yield expression, because the state name may change or vary because individual generator instances.

e.g. I want to do something like this (albeit this code doesn't work)

```
from random import random

class MyIter(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        context = {}
        for i in xrange(10):
            context[random()] = random()
            yield i

obj = MyIter()
i1 = iter(obj)
i2 = iter(obj)
while 1:
    try:
        i1.next()
        i2.next()
        print i1.context
        print i2.context
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Is there anyway to access local variables by inspecting Python's execution stack?

Comment: "I have a case where my generator manipulates a local state, and for unittests I want to inspect this state to ensure it contains the correct values." This makes no sense. The internal state of the generator is not a part of its interface, and thus not a candidate for unit testing. Unit tests are **not about** checking that the "right" algorithm is used; only about checking that a small, atomic piece of functionality gives the right **answer**. Just like every other testing worth doing. You wouldn't write the test so that inspects the source code, either, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *"Just like every other testing worth doing"* - What about the testing mentioned above [getgeneratorlocals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getgeneratorlocals) where it says *"The current internal state of the generator can also be queried. This is mostly useful for testing purposes, to ensure that internal state is being updated as expected"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but after digging into the generator interface, I found the exact path I need to access the generator's local variables:

```
from random import random

class MyIter(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        context = {}
        for i in xrange(10):
            context[random()] = random()
            yield i

obj = MyIter()
i1 = iter(obj)
i2 = iter(obj)
while 1:
    try:
        i1.next()
        i2.next()
        print i1.gi_frame.f_locals['context']
        print i2.gi_frame.f_locals['context']
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Ouch!  Don't do this, it's an implementation detail of CPython.  It might change with newer versions and be different for different implementations of Python (like Jython or IronPython).  And it's not very readable either...

Comment: I'm very unlikely to ever use Jython or IronPython, and both of these have a lot of incompatibilities with "standard" CPython functionality, but point well taken.

Comment: +1 While I would never rely on any code that has to access the internal state of a generator during normal operation, it *is* very useful to be able to get at this data during debugging given that there have been a few times when Python has left me wondering, "What were you even thinking??" (Also, I would never feel bad about answering my own question, unless the answer was a wrong one. ;) )

Comment: [inspect.getgeneratorlocals(generator)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getgeneratorlocals) now exists and uses this (but it's better to use that function).

Answer (score 1):

You should be treating the generator as a black box. Unit tests shouldn't care about its internal state, because that's just an implementation detail; they should only care about the specified behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, separate the iterator class from the container class:

```
from random import random

class MyContainer(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIter(self)

class MyIter(object):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container
        self.context = {}
        self.it = iter(xrange(10))
    def next(self):
        self.context[random()] = random()
        return next(self.it)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

obj = MyContainer()
# ...
```

I don't consider this very useful though...

Comment: Thanks. This is a very clean and OO approach, although it adds a little extra complexity.